# OpenGL on Linux, Accumulation Buffer doesn't do anything

Tags: linux, opengl, graphics, drivers

I have an OpenGL graphics project, a particle system to be exact, and I'm using such effects like an accumulation buffer implemented motion blur, and also using the standard smooth to anti-alias (I know there are better ways).

My problem is that they only work at university, on their machines.
University use linux, same as me, but unfortunately I don't know what graphics cards they use.

I have a desktop with an AMD Radeon HD 6800, and a linux installation on an external HDD which I'm working on. This is the set up that does not anti-alias or show the motion blur!

So I tried updating my graphics driver, but I'm finding that tough to do on linux...
Last time I tried it destroyed my installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the Open drivers on a pre-3.6 kernel then [MSAA & primitive smoothing simply isn't supported](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature#Feature_Matrix_for_Free_Radeon_Drivers).